# How does the catch method get called when chaining HTTP promises?

Tags: angular, http, typescript, promise

I have created a custom loaderService for my Angular application, that provides a loading spinner while a request (or a set of requests) is being handled by the back-end. Here is my code:

```
export class ComponentOne {
  constructor(loaderService: LoaderService, orderService: OrderService) {}
  ...
  ...
  method() {
    this.loaderService.display(true);
    this.orderService.firstRequest()
      // the misspelled word causes a 500 error
      .then((response) => this.orderService.methodWithWrongInput('misspelled_word'))
      // but it still executes the following then
      .then(() => this.method2())
      .catch(() => null)
      .then(() => this.loaderService.display(false));
  }
  ...
}
```

I display the spinner before the request, but I want to make sure I close it no matter if the request succeeds or fails. That's why I put a `catch` and final `then` at the bottom. The code works fine, but when I was debugging it I realized that even though the second request (with the intentionally misspelled word) fails, `method2()` is still being called. Or does it actually fail?

My question is, how does the catch method work when chaining requests. I thought if a request fails, we go straight to the catch method, but I might be wrong.

**Edit:** Turns out I was wrong about `method2()` being called. See T.J. Crowder's answer for more.

Comment: Hide the spinner in the `.finally()` block.

Comment: *"...I realized that even though the second request (with the intentionally misspelled word) fails, method2() is still being called."* No, it definitely will not be, if `methodWithWrongInput` throws, or returns a promise that ultimately rejects. (Note that the code as presented is missing a `)`.) The `then` handler containing `method2` would not be called; the `catch` following it would be.

Comment: @Sajal: Standard promises don't have `.finally` (yet). This `.catch(...).then(...)` idiom is the classic way to handle finally situations in the absense of one.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hmmm, I might be wrong then... So does that mean that as soon as a request fails, the `catch` method will be called?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, got it. I generally use `rxjs/Observable` which has `finally` block.

Comment: @BobbyBrown: The `catch` *callback*, yes.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It looks like I was mistaken that the next `then` method is being called since some promise chaining methods of some `Zone` class are being called. I guess internally it's more complicated than that. :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder and by the way, isn't the function inside the `.catch()` the callback?

Comment: @BobbyBrown: I've posted an answer going into details. *"It looks like I was mistaken that the next then method is being called..."* `then` **is** being called, synchronously, at the outset; what *isn't* being called is its callback containing `method2` (in the case where `methodWithWrongInput` throws or returns a promise that rejects). *"... isn't the function inside the `.catch()` the callback?"* Yes, one of several in the code. Why?

Comment: `// the misspelled word causes a 500 error`  +  `.catch(() => null)` = `dangerous code`  This can really bite you in the backside, handle errors you expect, and always reject the one's you don't..

Comment: @Keith I handle all the errors in the services themselves. Should I handle them in the components as well? I know that when using `Observable` you handle errors as you subscribe, meaning you don't do it in the service, but only in the component.

Comment: `.catch(() => null)` the problem is your not handling the error, your just ignoring it.  What if there is another reason why something failed, other than a 500 error.  It's going to be silently ignored.  We once spent days trying to track down a very strange error we was getting with a project we made, customer was getting well miffed I can tell you, data was disappearing etc.  As it turned out one of our coders was doing this `try { dosomething() }; catch() {}` all over the place.  As you can imagine, that coder no longer works for us..

Comment: @Keith I totally agree with you, but as I mentioned, I have an error handling method in the `orderService` itself. Therefore, when you call the `methodWithWrongInput`, and it throws an *internal server error*, it will be caught in the service (and console logged for example). Isn't that sufficient? It's a genuine question, since my code is still pretty shaky.

Comment: `Isn't that sufficient?`  No.. if that catch is ever hit, and this could be for a multitude of reasons, it's going to swallow any exception up, (bad).. actually (Bad) with a capital B.. If your saying all errors are handled in `methodWithWrongInput`, then remove the `catch` as the next `then` will get called anyway, as you have handled them inside `methodWithWrongInput`, my whole point is `.catch(() => null)` is a big no/no.  Try this -> place a deliberate error inside `methodWithWrongInput`, eg. First line before anything else do `throw new Error("Blah")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...I realized that even though the second request (with the intentionally misspelled word) fails, `method2()` is still being called...

I suspect you're misinterpreting what you're seeing in the debugger, which is easily done in this case.

In this code:

```
method() {
  this.loaderService.display(true);
  this.orderService.firstRequest()
    // the misspelled word causes a 500 error
    .then((response) => this.orderService.methodWithWrongInput('misspelled_word'))
    // but it still executes the following then
    .then(() => this.method2())
    .catch(() => null)
    .then(() => this.loaderService.display(false));
}
```

Here's what happens:

1. `this.loaderService.display(true);` runs
2. `this.orderService.firstRequest()` runs and returns a promise
3. `.then((response) => this.orderService.methodWithWrongInput('misspelled_word'))` runs — **not** the part inside the callback, just the `then`. It registers a resolution handler on the promise and returns a new promise.
4. `.then(() => this.method2())` runs — again, just the `then` call, not its callback. It returns another new promise.
5. `.catch(() => null)` runs — again, just the `catch` call, not its callback. It returns another new promise.
6. `.then(() => this.loaderService.display(false))` runs — again, just the `then` call, not its callback. It returns another new promise.

then **later**, the promise from `firstRequest()` resolves, and

7. `(response) => this.orderService.methodWithWrongInput('misspelled_word')` runs and returns a new promise

then **later**, that promise rejects, and

8. `() => null` (in your `catch` handler) runs and returns `null`, which resolves the associated promise (e.g., converts what was a rejection into a resolution)
9. `() => this.loaderService.display(false)` runs, because the chain is resolved (not rejected) at this point (thanks to #8 above)

So in the debugger, you'll see the execution cursor step over the `then` call for `method2`, during the initial sequence above (#4) where the chain is being set up synchronously; but that's just adding the handler to the chain. You *won't* see `method2` actually get called, because that callback is never triggered when the resolutions/rejections happen (in the case where `methodWithWrongInput` rejects)

Comment: A worthy notice would be that the .catch() method called as in the provided example will restore the promise chain, that explains why this.loaderService.display(false) kicks in and if the author wanted to catch the ultimate exception he would want to wrap the promise chain inside a Promise.all();

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been having a hard time understanding how promises work asynchronously, and this definitely brought some clarity.

Comment: @VadimG What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @BobbyBrown - He means that I should probably highlight that by returning a value from the `catch` handler, you're converting a rejection into a resolution. I think you know that, but that's what he's saying. I've added a bit to address it.

Comment: @BobbyBrown, in addition to T.J. Crowder's explanation I wanted to highlight that the catch in the chain block is not universal. It won't catch an exception in, say `this.orderService.firstRequest()`. Imagine having a chain of a dozen of promises -- for each one of them you would need to have it's own catch, unless you wrap them all in a promise and catch it instead. It might save some headache in a real world app.

Comment: What do you mean ? if a promise is rejected and another is created via `then` without the second argument ( or no arg at all ) then the second promise is rejected with the same error.

Comment: @VadimG But I was left with the impression that putting a `catch()` after a series of chained promises, it will be called if any of those promises fail. If I handle all of them identically (say with a `console.log`) then I can only use one `catch` method, correct?

Comment: at this point you are better off taking the time to read the specs. They are really not that hard, creating you own toy implementation is really not difficult and can serve as a good learning tool for understanding the language ( especiall y with regard to the event loop / stack execution ) : https://promisesaplus.com/ . Plus they have a package with tests for your implemation !

Comment: @adz5A: I hate to admit it but I might be wrong after all. Thanks for pointing that out. Having run a few more JSFiddles I was able to find out where the additional expections came from.
I apologize for providing confusing information >_<

Comment: @adz5A: Is your "What do you mean?" comment directed at me or Bobby or Vadim? If me, could you clarify?

Comment: @VadimG: *"I wanted to highlight that the catch in the chain block is not universal. It won't catch an exception in, say `this.orderService.firstRequest()`"* Not in `firstRequest`'s non-Promise code, no, that would just be an exception; it will see any exception thrown in the executor of the promise created by `firstRequest` (executor = function you pass `new Promise`) or in any of the `then` or `catch` handlers on that promise earlier in the chain.